# How i can place multiple controls in a particullar cell of TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I'm using a TableLayoutPanel control and in my scenario I have to place two controls inside of one particular cell, is that possible? If so, please elaborate.

Comment: Yeah @zapico, that worked, thx. To the point — instead of Panel I used one more TableLayoutPanel.

Answer (score 54):

You should use a Panel or any other content control inside that cell and then you'll be able to add many controls inside it.

Answer (score 7):

Put a tablelayout panel in the cell and give it two columns and one row. There's your two "cells".

Answer (score 4):

Put a Panel inside the cell and in that panel control you can place as many controls as you want

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

1) Create user control and place all control you want on it and than add new control in the cell

2) Put controls in the panel then put panel in the cell

Comment: it is too complicating doing this, using a Panel control is easier ;)